# Create own package repo for an offline Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, development, lts

I have some offline Ubuntu 18.04 LTS amd64 machines for sw development and I need to create a package repository for them. (or in worst case a directory containing the packages).
How can I solve this?
I need a collection of common c++ and python related packages (standard c++ libs, pip, numpy, ...)
with all dependencies.

Appreciate every answer

Edit: the point is how to get the packages on another (type of) system.

Answer (score 1):

We need to install one packege:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

**Creating a Debian package**

To do that we use the **dpkg-deb tool**. First of all, we need to create the **debian** package structure. The only files required to build a **debian** package are:

DEBIAN/control
custom files to be part of the package (not required)
First create a directory called **helloworld**. This directory will hold all necessary package files:

```
mkdir helloworld
```

Next, create the DEBIAN directory and the control file:

```
mkdir helloworld/DEBIAN
vi helloworld/DEBIAN/control
```

Inside the control file, we enter the following information:

```
Package: linuxconfig
Version: 1.0
Section: custom
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Essential: no
Installed-Size: 1024
Maintainer: linuxconfig.org
Description: Print linuxconfig.org on the screen
```

Great, the only thing that is missing is our `helloworld` program. Inside the `helloworld` directory we create a directory tree which represents the path where our program will be installed in the system, and copy the executable into it:

```
mkdir -p helloworld/usr/bin/
cp /path/to/helloworld helloworld/usr/bin/
```

At this point we are ready to create the package:

```
dpkg-deb --build helloworld 
dpkg-deb: building package `helloworld ' in `helloworld.deb'.
ls
linuxconfig  linuxconfig.deb
```

You may want to change the name of the package so that it includes the program version and the package architecture. For example:

```
mv helloworld.deb helloworld-1.0_amd64.deb
```

All done! Our package is ready! (**NOTE: this is just an example, the creation of official packages requires more work**).

Comment: Have you read the question?